# three.js is there a way to detect the clip position or when the far clip has been reached based on zoom?

Tags: three.js

For three.js, is there a way to detect the clip position or when the far clip has been reached based on the camera zoom? Or, some way to convert camera zoom to the same units as the camera near and far clip float values?

Comment: It would be great if you could elaborate a bit on what concrete problem you are trying to solve here. As it stands, it sounds like a bit of a misunderstanding about how clipping works (you can't "reach" the far clip plane), and can't really be answered imho.

Comment: it seems that if you zoom your camera out, the content goes beyond visible on the far clip plane - that is what i mea by "reaching" it (or escaping the far frustrum boundaries)

Comment: i guess another solution might be to interactively extend the far clip plane, when a user decides to go that far?

Comment: Ah, you want to set your camera near/far planes in such a way that your _content_ isn't clipped, given the current camera position, orientation and zoom level. That is one part of the common "zoom to fit" problem domain, there are relevant bits of code here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/camera-zoom-to-fit-object/936/3

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `.zoom` field on `PerspectiveCamera` only affects the camera's field of view and not the near or far clip planes. Here is where it's used when calculating the camera's projection matrix:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.js#L192

You can see how the zoom factor is affecting the field of view by using the `getEffectiveFOV` function:

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.getEffectiveFOV